# How to track down a AccessViolationException from a CLI project?

Tags: c++-cli, access-violation, memory-profiling

We got a CLI Wrapper that uses C++ Code written by another team. Since a few versions with very large changes in the sourcecode, we get randomly AccessViolationExceptions from the CLI. Its completely random, we tried to figure out under which circumstances the exception occurs - without success.

The Stacktrace is the following:

```
at QDataStream.{ctor}(QDataStream* , QByteArray* , QFlags<enum QIODevice::OpenModeFlag>* )
at XMLParsers.privGetCheckSumOf(XMLParsers* , ParameterManager* PM, ActiveFlag Active) 
at XMLParsers.Set_XMLStream(XMLParsers* , QXmlStreamWriter* pXSW, ParameterManager* PM, ActiveFlag Active)
at XMLParsers.ExportToExchangeFormat(XMLParsers* , QString* , ParameterManager* PM, ActiveFlag Active)
at XMLParsers.ExportToXML(XMLParsers* , basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> >* , ParameterManager* PM, ActiveFlag Active)
at ParameterManager.GetExchangeFormat(ParameterManager* , basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> >* , ActiveFlag Active)
```

My first step was to search the internet for exceptions when using QDataStream - but i did not found any. So my fear is now that some internal pointers are broken. The only strange thing is, that this exception just happens randomly with the very same input given. (about 1-2% of all calls)

Anyway, posting the original Sourcecode would be way too much here - the lines of codes invoked in the C++ code are several thousand, so my main question here is not in which specific line the exception has its origin, but rather how (in general) we can narrow down this AccessViolationException.

- Which memory profiling tool would you recommend? I assume that the call to the QDataStream Ctor above is not the reason of this exception, i think it's just the part where the (already invalid state of the class) can be detected.
- Can i get any further informations from an AccessViolationException? At the moment, my application just crashes and i'm only able to get the stacktrace from the windows event log.
- Any other hints what we could check / change in our CLI to find out detailed informations of this exception?

Any help is appreciated, as we're getting despaired of this bug after searching for many days (and nights..).